# Soccer results into amount of goals

Tags: r

I am using R

I do have Soccer results in a column (e.g. 2-2).
I now want to get a new column with the number of goals scored (e. g. 4).

How can I do that?

Column A (Team A)
Column B (Team B)
Column C (Result)
Column D (Amount of goals) --> has to be added

Comment: Please provide example data and expected result

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean something like this:

```
soc = data.frame(A = letters[1:10], 
                 B = letters[11:20], 
                 C = paste(sample(1:10),sample(1:10), sep = "-"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
soc$D = sapply(soc$C, function(x) sum(as.numeric(strsplit(x, split = "-")[[1]])))
soc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tidyR and dplyR packages

```
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(Result=c("2-2", "4-1", "0-0"))
df1 %>% separate(Result, c("team.A", "team.B")) %>% 
  mutate(ttl.Score = as.numeric(team.A) + as.numeric(team.B)) %>%
  select(ttl.Score)
```

Comment: If you want to keep all columns and the newly created ttl.Score remove the %>% select(ttl.Score) from the code above